# Calculate Columns to create Leaderboard

Tags: 2013, list, column, calculated-column

I have created an InfoPath form for a company-wide Step Competition that will have different communities competing against each other for walking the most amount of cumulative steps. Each form submission is published to a Sharepoint 2013 list. In the list, there are the following columns:

Name;
Employee ID Number;
Community;
Date;
Step Count

I would like to figure out a way to create a leaderboard that displays the total amount of steps per community. Any codeless or code-lite solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: So you tried a SharePoint View grouped on Community displaying the Sum of StepCount and it not work ???

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple no-code SharePoint Designer workflow.

For the purposes of these instructions, I'll call your first list (detailed above) your "Step Tracker" list. Now create a second list (which I'll call "Steps Leaderboard") and pre-populate it with your list of Communities. It's important the Community names are the same in each list - use a Lookup column if it helps.

Now, create a workflow in SharePoint Designer on the Step Tracker list, to run every time a list item is created. Set it up as follows:

```
[Set Workflow Variable] Set Variable:numOldSteps to Steps Leaderboard:Total Steps
[Do Calculation] then Calculate Variable:numOldSteps plus Current Item:Steps (Output to Variable:numNewSteps)
[Update List Item] then Update item in Steps Leaderboard
```

For the first and third lines of code, you'll need to do a lookup on the Community field. In both cases find the list item (in Steps Leaderboard) where the Community Field matches Current Item:Community.

Now publish the workflow, and for every future submission to the Step Tracker it will append that total to the appropriate Community in the Steps Leaderboard.

WARNING: This solution doesn't account for future revisions or deletions of entries in the Step Tracker list. You may want to lock out employees from editing their submissions without Full Control access (list settings > advanced settings > item-level permissions), and like with a timesheet instruct them to submit a second log entry with the +/- correction rather than edit or delete the first entry.

Hope this was helpful!